# TensorBoard: put a title on the tensorboard page

Tags: python, pytorch, customization, tensorboard, titlebar

I'm starting using tensorboard with pytorch. From the terminal with the command

```
tensorboard --logdir path
```

(where  `path`  is the path where the summary had been saved)
you can get a link for analize the summaries of the simualtion.
Since I have many simulation I'd like to label (put a title on)  the tensorboard page
Any Idea about how to do it?